# Flutter/Dart: How to do a slide animation on a group of images so they dont overlap

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I am creating an Anagrams Gold clone (Anagrams Gold is a game on the app store). I am trying to recreate the slide animation where after its verified the word you typed in is in the dictionary then the letter tiles (represented by images) of that word will slide to a player's side. It has to slide in a way that the images won't overlap each other in their final positions, there has to be padding so multiple words on a player's side don't overlap each other, and if the computer steals a word all the tile images in the right order need to slide to the computer side. A video of what I'm trying to do is attached below. Also I'm trying to create this using flutter and dart

Video Link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IVMnCHIM59sILlYFDM5qvM9QQ-EKP62P/view?usp=sharing

I have looked into docs on slide animation, tweens, but there is no detailed example/explanation of this animation I am trying to do

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.